# Spark MLLib TFIDF implementation for LogisticRegression

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-spark-mllib, tf-idf

I try to use the new TFIDF algorithem that spark 1.1.0 offers. I'm writing my job for MLLib in Java but I can't figure out how to get the TFIDF implementation working. For some reason [IDFModel](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/org/apache/spark/mllib/feature/IDFModel.html) only accepts a [JavaRDD](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/org/apache/spark/api/java/JavaRDD.html) as input for the method [transform](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/org/apache/spark/mllib/feature/IDFModel.html#transform%28org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaRDD%29) and not simple Vector. **How can I use the given classes to model a TFIDF vector for my LabledPoints?**

*Note: The document lines are in the format [Label; Text]*

---

Here my code so far:

```
        // 1.) Load the documents
        JavaRDD<String> data = sc.textFile("/home/johnny/data.data.new"); 

        // 2.) Hash all documents
        HashingTF tf = new HashingTF();
        JavaRDD<Tuple2<Double, Vector>> tupleData = data.map(new Function<String, Tuple2<Double, Vector>>() {
            @Override
            public Tuple2<Double, Vector> call(String v1) throws Exception {
                String[] data = v1.split(";");
                List<String> myList = Arrays.asList(data[1].split(" "));
                return new Tuple2<Double, Vector>(Double.parseDouble(data[0]), tf.transform(myList));
            }
        });

        tupleData.cache();

        // 3.) Create a flat RDD with all vectors
        JavaRDD<Vector> hashedData = tupleData.map(new Function<Tuple2<Double,Vector>, Vector>() {
            @Override
            public Vector call(Tuple2<Double, Vector> v1) throws Exception {
                return v1._2;
            }
        });

        // 4.) Create a IDFModel out of our flat vector RDD
        IDFModel idfModel = new IDF().fit(hashedData);

        // 5.) Create Labledpoint RDD with TFIDF
        ???
```

**Solution**  *from Sean Owen*:

```
        // 1.) Load the documents
        JavaRDD<String> data = sc.textFile("/home/johnny/data.data.new"); 

        // 2.) Hash all documents
        HashingTF tf = new HashingTF();
        JavaRDD<LabeledPoint> tupleData = data.map(v1 -> {
                String[] datas = v1.split(";");
                List<String> myList = Arrays.asList(datas[1].split(" "));
                return new LabeledPoint(Double.parseDouble(datas[0]), tf.transform(myList));
        }); 
        // 3.) Create a flat RDD with all vectors
        JavaRDD<Vector> hashedData = tupleData.map(label -> label.features());
        // 4.) Create a IDFModel out of our flat vector RDD
        IDFModel idfModel = new IDF().fit(hashedData);
        // 5.) Create tfidf RDD
        JavaRDD<Vector> idf = idfModel.transform(hashedData);
        // 6.) Create Labledpoint RDD
        JavaRDD<LabeledPoint> idfTransformed = idf.zip(tupleData).map(t -> {
            return new LabeledPoint(t._2.label(), t._1);
        });
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`IDFModel.transform()` accepts a `JavaRDD` or `RDD` of `Vector`, as you see. It does not make sense to compute a model over a single `Vector`, so that's not what you're looking for right?

I assume you're working in Java, so you mean you want to apply this to a `JavaRDD<LabeledPoint>`. `LabeledPoint` contains a `Vector` and a label. IDF is not a classifier or regressor, so it needs no label. You can `map` a bunch of `LabeledPoint` to just extract their `Vector`.

But you already have a `JavaRDD<Vector>` above. TF-IDF is merely a way of mapping words to real-valued features based on word frequencies in the corpus. It also does not output a label. Maybe you mean you want to develop a classifier from TF-IDF-derived feature vectors, and some other labels you already have?

Maybe that clears things up but otherwise you'd have to greatly clarify what you are trying to achieve with TF-IDF.

Comment: Let assume I have a dataset with (label,id,vector). I see no way to compute it to a TF-IDF model and somehow remap each vector back to it's id and/or label after I got the JavaRDD<Vector> back from IDFModel.transform(). I hope it clarifies a bit the problem I'm facing..

Comment: Ah I made a bit of a mistake here. It's `IDF` that computes the frequencies. Yes it would make more sense if `IDFModel` operated on a single `Vector` too. You can make a pull request for it. In the meantime this may work: 1. Persist input RDD. 2. Transform it to just vectors and apply `IDFModel` 3. `zip` with original RDD 4. transform label and new vector to `LabeledPoint`

Comment: Yeah that were my thoughst too, will make a pull request .. thanks anyway

Comment: @SeanOwen applying the IDFModel won't change the order will it? Because zip is basically just doing an ordered 1:1 match right? Or am I thinking about this wrong?

Comment: Hi @SeanOwen how do I create JavaRDD<LabeledPoint> if I have all the features/column of String type? I want to use my dataset in RandomForest machine learning model